# How to update sub array item in MongoDB, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So let's say I have this piece of code:

```
const old = await Sports.findById(sportId);
```

And it returns the following:

```
{
    _id: "sdsdsds",
    name: "sdsdsds",
    enabled: true,
    markets: [
        {
            enabled: true,
            defId: "LOOKATME",
            name: "sdsdsd",
        },
        {
            enabled: false,
            defId: "dfsdfdsfs",
            name: "sdsdfsdsd",
        },
    ]
}
```

Now, let's say I want to update the market with the defId of "LOOKATME" so it enabled becomes false.
Would it be possible to added inside an update function such as this:

```
const updated = await Sports.findByIdAndUpdate(old, [LOGIC], {new: true});
```

How would I go about doing this so the output is this:

```
{
    _id: "sdsdsds",
    name: "sdsdsds",
    enabled: true,
    markets: [
        {
            enabled: false, // this is what changed
            defId: "LOOKATME",
            name: "sdsdsd",
        },
        {
            enabled: false,
            defId: "dfsdfdsfs",
            name: "sdsdfsdsd",
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const updated = await Sports.updateOne({_id: old._id, "markets.defId": "LOOKATME"}, {$set: {"markets.$.enabled": false}}, {new: true});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This worked perfectly after changing `updateOne` to `findOneAndUpdate`, thank you!